# Нужно посчитать сумму арифметической прогрессии с помощью рекурсии

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Нужно посчитать сумму арифметической прогрессии с помощью рекурсии с вводимыми данными:

- значение первого элемента
- разница
- размер

Вот код, но у меня ничего не выходит с настройкой данных вводимых с консоли.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class progressionRec
{
public:
  void operator()(int a1, int d, int n) {
    ++count;
    if(n <= 1){
      cout << a1 << " ";
    } else {
      int next = a1 + d;
      operator()(next, d, n - 1);
      cout << a1 << " ";
    }
  }


  size_t getCount() const
  {
    return count;
  }

private:
  std::size_t count = 0;
};

int main()
{

    auto func = progressionRec();
    func(2,3,15);
    std::cout << "\nCount:" << func.getCount() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А **суммировать** кто будет?...

Comment: если вам не сложно у меня появился новый вопрос в профиле, мне очень срочно нужен по нему ответ, вы б не могли помочь и ответить?

Comment: Чтобы обратиться к конкретному пользователю лучше пишите @ а потом его никнейм. Например @ПавелЕриков так пользователь увидит оповещение, что ему написали

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Хорошо, спасибо так и буду делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и писал Harry: "*А **суммировать** кто будет?*"

Решение: просто добавить первой строчкой в `operator()` суммирование `sum += a1`, и получать сумму можно так же через функцию `getSum()`

Можно также вынести рекурсию в дополнительную функцию, и каждый вызов `operator()` обнулять `sum` и `count`.

```
void operator()(int a1, int d, int n) {
    count = 0;
    sum = 0;
    nextTerm(a1, d, n);
}
```

В функции `nextTerm` очевидно нужно вызывать рекурсивно её же, а не `operator()`

Вывод программы при вызове `func(2, 3, 15)` и `func(2, 3, 3)`:

[image: Результат]

P.s. если вы хотите вывод в обратном порядке, то поместите `cout` перед рекурсивным вызовом `nextTerm`